# Links are underlined under Firefox but not under Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, text-decorations

I have made [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zbr64fn/embedded/result/).

It works as intended under Chrome, but under Firefox it adds the underlines under the links while I clearly specify `text-decoration: none` in CSS for every link.

This is the code from the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zbr64fn/

I include it below as well:

HTML

```
<div id="footerSlider">
    <div class="fade" id="fade0">
        <a href="#">
            <table class="footerTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="footerImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/xr54kxd.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="footerText">
                            <a href="#">Something clever</a>
                            <br>
                            <div class="footerSublinks">
                                <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 1</a> <span class="split">|</span> <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 2</a> <span class="split">|</span> <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fade" id="fade1">
        <a href="#">
            <table class="footerTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="footerImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/du8oCqW.png">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="footerText">
                            <a href="#">A very nice island</a>
                            <br>
                            <div class="footerSublinks">
                                <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 4</a> <span class="split">|</span> <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 5</a> <span class="split">|</span> <a class="footerSublink" href="#">CHOICE 6</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footerSlider {
    width: 986px;
    height: 168px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

 .fade {
    height: 137px;
}

.footerImage {
    float: left;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.footerText {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    height: 137px;
}

.footerText > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #58595b;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.footerText:before {
    content: "";
    width: 29px;
    height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 8px 0 0 -20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/RpRclne.png);
}

.footerSublinks a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: #292564;
    transition: color 0.8s ease;
}

.footerSublinks a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #F00;
}

.split {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    color: #292564;
}

.footerTable {
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var loopInterval = 5000;

$(document).ready(function(){
    allFades = $(".fade");

    var fadesLength = allFades.length;
    var nextIndex = 0;

    fadesHtml = [];

    allFades.each(function(index){
        fadesHtml.push($(this).html());
        if(index!=0){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    function loopFade(){
        $("#fade0").fadeOut(500,  function(){
            nextIndex++;
            if(nextIndex>(fadesLength-1)){
                nextIndex=0;
            }
            $("#fade0").html(fadesHtml[nextIndex]).fadeIn(500);
        });
    }

    setInterval(loopFade, loopInterval);

});
```

Comment: it isn't the text-decoration. you can see that when you hover over it the underline comes in red and looks different than the blue line. (I'm still looking around)

Comment: The code has nested `a` elements. This is invalid in all HTML versions and very confusing, and we should *expect* differences in browser behavior (error recovery). You should correct the HTML markup. And you should explain why JavaScript is relevant here, or remove it if it isn’t.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment @JukkaK.Korpela Why are nested `a` elements invalid? How am I supposed to do the whole background clickable (and make it go to an address) and make the links in front of it clickable as well (and point to another address) ?

Answer (score 1):

The outer anchor tag you wrap around .footerTable is causing this. I modified your fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/6zbr64fn/2/,  and included this which only selects the anchor you have wrapping the table element.

```
.fade > a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't styled or addressed the actual anchor tag right under the .fade div.

You can easily override the behaviour by doing:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

but that would be a very strong statement specificity-wise (more on the subject: [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)), so I would personally recommend to give a class name to the links you want to prevent default behaviour, and do so.

For example, using the class `.no-underline` and have it apply the following css:

```
.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And in you markup:

```
<div id="footerSlider">
<div class="fade" id="fade0">
    <a href="#" class="no-underline">
        <table class="footerTable">
```